# Can't get setValue to work correctly in GoogleScripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding and I'm trying to create a simple button in Google Sheets that will take the data from the "input" tab and populate the last empty cells of the appropriate columns in the "feeding" tab. I have it working to log the values of the feedings & date, but can't seem to get them to move.

Here's the code:

```
//Gets data from 'Input' sheet
function recordData() {
  let src = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input'); //Source
  let dst = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Feedings'); //Destination

  let input = {};
    input.milk = src.getRange('B2').getValue()
    input.formula = src.getRange('B3').getValue()
  let today = new Date();
    today.date = today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate();
    today.formatTime = function formatAMPM (time) {
    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    var endTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " "+ ampm;
    return endTime;
    }
    today.time = today.formatTime (new Date);

  Logger.log("formula = " + input.formula);
  Logger.log("milk = " + input.milk);
  Logger.log("date = "+ today.date);
  Logger.log("time = "+ today.time);


//moves data from 'Input' to 'Feeding' sheet. **NOT WORKING**
  function moveData () {
        var dstFeedings = {};
          dstFeedings.date = dst.getRange("Feedings!A2:A").getLastrow.setValues(today.date);
          dstFeedings.time = dst.getRange("Feedings!B2:B").getLastRow.setValues(today.time);
          dstFeedings.formula = dst.getRange("Feedings!C2:C").getLastRow.setValues(input.formula);
          dstFeedings.milk = dst.getRange("Feedings!D2:D").getLastRow.setValues(input.milk);
        return dstFeedings;
      }  
}
```

[Here's the link to a copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P8RUto0nBhRNiQ0NBXkSU0MEN9miZR0z1C0kSZEBk14/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question has at least two problems, `getLastRow` and `setValues`, on

```js
dstFeedings.date = dst.getRange("Feedings!A2:A").getLastrow.setValues(today.date);
dstFeedings.time = dst.getRange("Feedings!B2:B").getLastRow.setValues(today.time);
dstFeedings.formula = dst.getRange("Feedings!C2:C").getLastRow.setValues(input.formula);
dstFeedings.milk = dst.getRange("Feedings!D2:D").getLastRow.setValues(input.milk);
```

- `getLastRow` hasn't a `setValues` method.
- `setValues` requires and Array having an Array for each row, the inner Array, should have a value or Date object for each row's cell. Since the variables used hold a single value / Date object, `setValue` should be used instead of `setValues`.

Related

- [More efficient way too look up the last row in a specific column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14818902/1595451)
- [Finding an empty cell in a column using google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662987/1595451)
- [How to find the last cell with a value at the end of a column that is shorter than other columns in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62393563/1595451)